# Why Wordpress strips scr string from img tag off?

Tags: images

If I add a code, for example

```
<a class="thickbox" title="Image" href="image.jpg">
    <img scr="image.jpg" alt="image" width="100" height="100" border="0" />
</a>
```

WordPress changes it after visiting Visual side:

```
<a class="thickbox" title="Image" href="image.jpg">
    <img alt="image" width="100" height="100" border="0" />
</a>
```

What makes scr string disappear? The copy/paste used to work before.

Answer (score 2):

Because the correct attribute is `src`. S.R.C, not S.C.R. (I'd have assumed it was a typo in the question, but you used it 3 times).

The WordPress editor removes attributes that aren't whitelisted, and since `scr` isn't an actual attribute it's not on the whitelist.